# Selenium XPATH for dynamic class for dropdown

Tags: selenium

I am new to selenium and I am having trouble to write an `xpath` selector for this `dropdown element`:

```
<li style="" class="dropdown open" data-bind="visible: currentServers().length > 0">
<a id="employeeList" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" data-bind="text: currentServerName()">employee servers</a>
<ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
```

I have tried various `xpath` and it was not able to click on the dropdown.

Can any one help me with the `xpath`? I have used xpath with `id , class, cssselector` . But none of them worked.

Comment: Can you try the xpath `"//li[@class='dropdown']"` ?

Comment: Also, edit your question to include what you have tried so far and how you are clicking on the dropdown? What is your aim?( maybe you don't even have to click on the dropdown)

Comment: Yes, I have tried the following . But It did not work. WebElement divClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='dropdown']/li"));
  divClick.click();    Yes, I want to click on the dropdown. I have also tried li[@class='dropdown open ']/l.  When we click on the dropdown the class attribute changes to dropdown open.

Comment: Try this `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='dropdown.open']"));`

Comment: Yes , Tried the following - WebElement divClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='dropdown.open']"));
  divClick.click();   Still did not work.     Also, used  WebElement divClick = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@class='dropdown  open']"));
  divClick.click();  But it did not work

Comment: Ok, so I think that either the element is not available for interaction or the xpath that we are using is not unique, hence it's fetching the wrong one. Can you add what is the error/outpur you are getting?

Comment: I am getting the following error.  Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//li[@class='dropdown']/li"}
Command duration or timeout: 24 milliseconds

Comment: Can you provide the source link?

Answer (score 0):

If the root issue is the `li` element changes its class when opened - as stated in the comments, then the solution would be not to go after an exact match in it, but rather containing the looked for string. I.e.:

```
//li[contains(@class, "dropdown")]
```

Prepend/append any other elements as needed (e.g. an `a` element beneath it,  if it is the one to relieve the click, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this way.

**Explanation:** Your `html` inside the `li` tag, so start your `xpath` with `li` tag and then move ahead with `a` tag along with `text` method.

```
//li/a[contains(text(), 'employee servers')]
```

Comment: Does my explanation of code helped you? If it does then please mark this answer as `Accepted` if it's resolved your issue.